# Mysterious Flink 0.10 SNAPSHOT runtime error

Tags: apache-flink

I have this code with Flink 0.10 SNAPSHOT and I get a runtime error that I don't quite understand.

Here's the code:

```Java
    DataStream<Thing> kafkaThings = env.addSource(
            new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<Thing>(
                    "thing_data",              // Topic to read from
                    new ThingSchema(reader),   // Deserializer (provided as util)
                    props)
    );

    kafkaThings
        .flatMap(new ThingFlatMapper())
        .addSink(new ThingSink());
```

And here's the runtime error at the `flatMap()` step (I think...):

```
06:16:20.145 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 - Uncaught fatal error from thread [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down ActorSystem [flink]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$class.receive(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:33) ~[flink-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$LogMessages$$super$receive(JobManager.scala:100) ~[flink-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$class.receive(LogMessages.scala:26) ~[flink-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.receive(JobManager.scala:100) ~[flink-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:567) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:587) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:460) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:482) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

I think it's there because I have breakpoints set on both the `addSource` and in the `ThingFlatMapper.flatMap` method. It gets to the first but not the second.

I'm thinking it's a simple configuration error but the error message is not exactly helpful (at least for me).

Thoughts?

(As an afterthought, it might make sense to have my build dependencies listed here - here's the flink-related lines from my `build.gradle`:

```
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-clients:${project['flink.version']}"
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kafka:${project['flink.version']}"
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-core:${project['flink.version']}"
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-java:${project['flink.version']}"
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer:${project['flink.version']}"
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java:${project['flink.version']}"
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-runtime:${project['flink.version']}"
compile "org.apache.flink:flink-java8:${project['flink.version']}"
```

flink.version is set to `1.0-SNAPSHOT`, and I'm running this from inside IDEA.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your build system. Which Scala version you use for the build? Flink defaults to Scala 2.10 at the moment. For Scala 2.11, please add the _2.11 suffix like in flink-clients_2.11.

Comment: The `akka-actor_2.11` dependency indicates that you're indeed mixing Scala `2.10` with Scala `2.11` dependencies.